# How to express misusing a tool

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, phrasal-verbs

I am not a native English speaker. I was wondering how to express the situation in which one uses a tool for something other than what it was meant to be, and in a bad way so that you are not doing your best, or you are hurting yourself with your ignorance about the tool you use.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is my favorite:

> What you're doing is like slicing a loaf of bread with a hammer.

Answer (score 13):

There is a related proverb, that says:

> If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail

which means, according to the [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_all_you_have_is_a_hammer,_everything_looks_like_a_nail):

1. With limited tools, single-minded people apply them inappropriately or indiscriminately
2. If a person is familiar with a certain, single subject/has with them a certain, single instrument, they may have a confirmation bias to believe that it is the answer to/involved in everything.

Answer (score 9):

A common phrase for this is:

> You're trying to fit a square peg in a round hole.

The idea is that you can't fit a square peg in a round hole; you should be using a circular peg instead.

Other than that, feel free to pick your favorite from one of these:

> You're using the wrong tool.
>   You should use a voltage meter.
>   You shouldn't use an ammeter, because you're trying to measure voltage, not current.
>   You might find this easier if you use a compass, instead.

Comment: I wonder what task it is that can be done with either a voltmeter or a compass but not with an ammeter. :)

Comment: Do you say "you should use a voltage meter" when somebody is using the wrong tool?

Comment: If you measure a voltage from a sufficiently powerful source using an ammeter then you will at least blow a fuse, or destroy the meter.

Comment: I think the compass is a joke, as it would be equally unsuitable to the task as the tool used.

Comment: Actually, voltage and current are directly related so even though the tool is not ideal you can infer voltage from current readings (via the resistance of the meter). So it's a bad analogy

Answer (score 4):

A phrase I grew up with is "a Glasgow screwdriver."

This is in fact a hammer, and refers to the practice of fastening screws with a hammer instead of the correct tool.

Answer (score 2):

A native English speaker, in a natural situation, would probably say:

> That's the wrong thing to use. You should use this (hands over the correct tool)

Comment: The question asks “how to express the situation,” not what to say in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

"You can't stomp a snake with both feet in a bucket".  (From Dave Barry, originally)

Answer (score 0):

Though not quite exactly what I think you are asking for (the wrong tool can be dangerous to use), I like this from Robert Frost's poem Two Tramps In Mud Time:

> Except as a fellow handled an ax  They had no way of knowing a fool.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the hammer-nail answer, what immediately hit my head was the old saying:

> A fool with a tool is still a fool.